# In Azure how to join a VM to the Update Manager (automation account) as a post provisioning step from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, updates, azure-automation

I'm trying to automate the onboard process of a VM in the Update Manager (automation account) as a post provisioning step from PowerShell.

Make the test with 4 VMs. I onboarded 2 of them manually from the azure portal and the other 2 I used the following command:

```
Set-AzVMExtension -ExtensionName "UpdateManagement" `
                    -Location $location `
                    -ResourceGroupName  $resourceGroupName `
                    -VMName $vmName `
                    -Publisher "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
                    -ExtensionType "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
                    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.0" `
                    -Settings @{"workspaceId" = $workspaceId;
                                "azureResourceId" = $resourceId;
                                "AutomationAccountURL"=$registrationUrl;
                                "AzureAutomationAccountId"=$aaId;
                                "stopOnMultipleConnections"= $True} `
                    -ProtectedSettings @{
                      "workspaceKey" = $workspaceKey;
                      "vmResourceId" = $resourceId
                    }
```

All four VMs were added to the Log analytics workspace linked to the automation account.

VM's linked to the Log Analytics Workspace

[image]

But only the ones configured manually were added to the update management in the Automation Account.

Automation account update management

[image]

Not sure if I'm missing a step.

I have tested multiple settings options.
Also, find this [Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/enable-from-runbook) from the gallery. The problem is that it uses Run as account configuration, which is going to be deprecated this year. Another issue is that it is based on an already onboarded machine.

Answer (score 0):

***Check below steps to resolve/troubleshoot this kind of issue:***

Verify whether the Log Analytics workspace is associated with the Automation Account using below command:

```
$workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -Name <workspaceName>
Get-AzAutomationAccount -Name <automationAccountName> -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName>
```

[image]

[image]

If it is not giving the exact results, then link the workspace using
 [`Set-AzAutomationAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/set-azautomationaccount?view=azps-9.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.3.0) command as detailed in MSDoc.

And you can also check whether the VMs have been added to the Update Management solution.

If it is not existing, the VMs were not added to the Update Management solution. Create a software update configuration to add the VMs to the Update Management solution using
[`New-AzAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationsoftwareupdateconfiguration?view=azps-9.5.0) command as detailed in MSDoc.